# Logout on Apollo-Client

Tags: typescript, react-native, apollo-client

I'm developing an app using react-native with Expo that interacts with a GraphQL Backend using Apollo.

The authorization between Front and Back is done with JWT token on header and it's working fine. On backend there is a Middleware that checks if the token exists and is valid:

- If the query is open, it just retrieve the info.
- If the query is authorized and the user is authenticated it retrieves the info.
- If the query is authorized but the user is not logged in (or using an invalid token) it throws an error.

**BACKEND**

```js
export const isAuth: MiddlewareFn<MyContext> = ({ context }, next) => {
    const { authorization } = context.req.headers;

    if (!authorization) {
        throw new Error("Not authenticated. ");
    }
[...]
}

@Query(() => User)
@UseMiddleware(isAuth)
async Me(
    @Ctx() { payload }: MyContext,
) {
    return UserModel.findById(payload!.userId);
}
```

The way I'm getting the queryes is through the following component:

**FRONTEND**

```js
const Me: React.FC<any> = (props) => {
    const {
        data, loading, error,
    } = useMeQuery();

    if (loading) {
        return (<Text>Loading ... {String(props.test)}</Text>);
    }
    if (error) {
        return (<Text>{ error.message } {String(props.test)}</Text>);
    }
    return (
        <Text>Hello { String(data?.Me?.email) } </Text>
    );
};
```

Being `useMeQuery();` a hook function generated by `@graphql-codegen/cli`.

```js
export function useMeQuery(baseOptions?: ApolloReactHooks.QueryHookOptions<MeQuery, MeQueryVariables>) {
        return ApolloReactHooks.useQuery<MeQuery, MeQueryVariables>(MeDocument, baseOptions);
}
```

Up to here it is working fine.

Now, I'm trying to implement the Logout functionallity on the frontend so the user can keep navigating as an anonimous user when logged out.

I just created a button that calls a function that clears the stored tokens (it is working), so the next calls are not authenticated and throws an error. The problem I'm getting on is that apollo-client is using cache to rerender the query, so the now anonimous user is able to see the old-LogedIn user information.

In order to Logout, I tried several ways to clear cache, without succeed:

```js
clearTokens(); // Clear tokens from asyncStorage. Working fine.

// Tying to clear cache:
client.clearStore(); // Not working, still getting the stored value on cache when refreshing the component.
client.cache.reset(); // Not working, still getting the stored value on cache when refreshing the component.
client.resetStore(); // Not working, it tries to call the query again, it throws an error (because it is not authenticated) and doesn't clear the cache.
```

Which is the best way in order to Logout when using `apollo-client`?

PD: If another user is logged in, I call the `client.resetStore();` and the queryes all refetched, working properly. The problem is just to pass from loggedIn to anonimous.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

On other topics I read about this issue but using React. They talk about navigating to another page, however, on react-native, it was not working because when navigating to another page, the last page keeps opened. The solution was to navigate to another page using `props.navigation.replace("Logout");`.

Logout page just do whatever it has to do, clears the cache with `client.clearStore();` and then automatically navigates to the main one using navigation.replace.

Answer (score 0):

For apollo v3 I had to do both of them:

```js
client.clearStore();
client.cache.gc();
```